# Is there a filter for indexing/searching ordinals as their numeric values?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to index and search 101st, 101nd, etc, as 101, 102, etc. Does ElasticSearch have a filter that does that?

Comment: Your suggestion worked beautifully. It just took me a while to get back to this as I got diverted on to other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [pattern_replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) char filter, to create tokens like `101`, `102` from the text `101st`, `101nd` or `102`.

I created a custom-analyzer which removed text and keep only the number so that searching for `100`, `102` `10` matches the tokens in the inverted index and comes in the search result.

### Working example

### Index def for custom analyzer using pattern_replace.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "my_char_filter"
                    ],
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "my_char_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "[a-z]+", --> note this
                    "replacement": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

test this [custom-analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) using the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

```
POST /{your-index-name}/_analyze

    {
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "text": "101nd"
    }

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "101",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

### Another sample

POST /{your-index-name}/_analyze

```
{
    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
    "text": "102st"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "102",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```